# Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS: problem installing curl

Tags: dpkg, lts, curl

I'm starting on a fresh Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS desktop installation, but can't install curl:

```
student@laptop:~/osm-install$ sudo apt install curl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 curl : Depends: libcurl3-gnutls (= 7.47.0-1ubuntu2) but 7.47.0-1ubuntu2.8         is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Same happens (with other dependencies) for VLC and other packages. I'm tied to Ubuntu 16.04.5 and, frankly speaking, being an LTS I wasn't expecting all these problems.

Best,
/Pedro A

Adding apt policy curl libcurl3-gnutls:

```
student@laptop:~$ apt policy curl libcurl3-gnutls
curl:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 7.47.0-1ubuntu2
  Version table:
     7.47.0-1ubuntu2 500
        500 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
libcurl3-gnutls:
  Installed: 7.47.0-1ubuntu2.8
  Candidate: 7.47.0-1ubuntu2.8
  Version table:
 *** 7.47.0-1ubuntu2.8 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     7.47.0-1ubuntu2 500
        500 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and add the output of the command `apt policy curl libcurl3-gnutls` please? That will show what versions of these packages are available for you and where they come from. Probably you have added external repositories that contain conflicting versions for one of them.

Comment: I've also tried with the 'main server'... same result. Similar problem trying to install `openssh-server`

Comment: I have retried with a fresh install, no help. Another victim is `libvirt-bin`. This reaches the *PANIC* level :-(

Answer (score 0):

First, clear your local package cache with

```
sudo apt clean
```

That prevents `apt` from trying to install cached package versions which are not downloadable from a repository at the moment.

Then, as you already have the incompatible version of `libcurl3-gnutls` installed, you'll need to downgrade that version when you install `curl`, by specifying the exact version you want:

```
sudo apt install curl libcurl3-gnutls=7.47.0-1ubuntu2
```

If you get the same error for other packages too, you can use the same method.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice, I'll try and come back.